# Integrate Firebase GoogleSignIn using Carthage

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, carthage

I'm trying to integrate *Firebase GoogleSignIn* using *Carthage*. I used 5.0.1 version integrated by *Cocoapods* and everything works just fine. Then I switched to *Carthage* and the `GIDSignInDelegate` is called immediately after I call `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()` with *errorCode* `-1`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the discussion at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3791:

There is potentially a solution at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk. If that doesn't work, see the additional discussion about workarounds in the [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3791).

A pure Firebase Carthage approach is targeted for an early November release.